# How to change the template for autogenerated pom.xml file in Eclipse maven

Tags: pom.xml, maven-eclipse-plugin

Whenever I create a new Maven project in Eclipse Juno, it creates a pom.xml file by default. The file has got some dependencies e.g. Junit 3.8.1 I'd like to change the template for this autogenerated file so the dependency created is for JUnit 4 not JUnit3 by default.